# Read-only access to Siteminder administration console

Tags: siteminder

Is it possible to give someone access to the SiteMinder administration console, but in a read only fashion?  We want some people to be able to see the configuration but not be able to modify anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SiteMinder Administrator accounts can be configured with fine-grained privileges that determine the administrative capabilities available to that administrator.

SiteMinder Administrator accounts are assigned rights to one or more security categories that define their administrative authority in the Administrative UI, such as managing authentication schemes. By default an Administrator account has access to every SiteMinder object related to an assigned security category.

Workspaces define a subset of SiteMinder objects. Assign a workspace to one or more Administrator accounts to filter the objects that are available to them, further controlling the scope of their administrative authority. An Administrator account whose authority is restricted by an assigned workspace is known as a scoped administrator.

Consult the SiteMinder Policy Server Configuration guide for more details...

Comment: Looks like Workspaces are a feature in 12.5.  I have both versions, but the instance I am in is 12.0 at the moment.  Thanks for the info.